# Android compass on different phone orientation

Tags: android, navigation

I'm building an application using the copass sensor. If the phone is placed horizontally it's providing the correct angles. But it is intend to be placed vertically (eg for car mounting) How can I get proper compass directions in this situation?

```
if (sensorEvent.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE)
        return;

    switch (sensorEvent.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            gravity = sensorEvent.values.clone();
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            geomag = sensorEvent.values.clone();
            break;
    }

    if (gravity != null && geomag != null) {
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(inR, I,
                gravity, geomag);
        if (success) {
            SensorManager.getOrientation(inR, orientVals);
            azimuth = Math.toDegrees(orientVals[0]);
            pitch = Math.toDegrees(orientVals[1]);
            roll = Math.toDegrees(orientVals[2]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Given the compass uses a geomagnetic sensor, it doesn't matter the orientation.  If you're not seeing the correct values, it's most likely that you're misinterpreting the sensor results.  Of course to help with that we'd need your code.

Comment: Added the code sample

Answer (score 0):

One or two axes may be "compressed" due to roll and pitch, but the internal matrix operations compensate for it. The compensation may result in a jerky movement to the human eye, against which I suggest to use an animation. Therefore, only Azimuth is relevant to your application.

Comment: Heading the phone to North in horizontal Position returns correctly 0°. Heading the front camera to North when it's vertical oriented compass values are wrong. Moving from horizontal to vertical changes the values to getting more and more unreliable. So I need to use pitch in any way

Comment: If it is vertical at 90 degrees (right-up) then yes, the indications are relative to the magnetic field inclination and completely off. For normal circumstances however, up to a pitch or roll of say 45 degrees, the compass should return the horizontal coordinates.

Comment: By the way, if you look for 3D game programming, and specifically for 3D to 2D matrix projections, you may find the formulas which suit you. I strongly suppose however that the computational work is correctly done by the hardware itself.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had to add:

```
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(inR, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z,
            remappedRotationMatrix);
```